# $\Bbb{R}^3 - S^1$ deformation retracts to $S^2 \vee S^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

I'm reading this [blog post](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences?rq=homotopy) where they state that $\Bbb{R}^3 - S^1$ deformation retracts to $S^2 \vee S^1$ and then they proceed to give the following sketch

[image]

with the explanation

> You can see this in the drawing above where $X = \Bbb R^3 \setminus \{ \text{circle} \}$ consists of the space inside the yellow cube including the blue disc, but not including the white boundary of that disc. (That white part is our deleted circle which I will from now on refer to as "our/the circle.") Notice that our circle sits on some plane in $\Bbb R^3$. (I've shaded it in dark yellow.) Then all the points lying on that plane outside of the circle (the dark yellow bit) along with the points in $\Bbb R^3$ not on the plane (the light yellow bit) deformation retract onto a sphere. (So basically, everything that's yellow maps to a sphere.) And all the points enclosed by the circle (the blue disc) deformation retract onto a line, i.e. the diameter of our sphere.

The **white circle** is not very clear from the picture, but it's the boundary of the blue disc in the first picture if someone misses it.

I usually understand the process, but here the first $\simeq$ feel very odd. Where does the white circle go? Also are we including the inner part of the "sphere" in this deformation or is it just the boundary? I know that $\Bbb R^3$ can be deformed to the three dimensional disc $D^3$ and $\Bbb R^3 - \{ \text{point} \}$ to $S^2$.

It's added on the blog later that

> **Added May 22, 2016**: I realize (Thank you, readers!) that the description of the first homotopy equivalence in the picture above is a bit cryptic. And to make matters worse, that horizontal blue line should really be vertical! Yikes. So instead of trying to illuminate (and thus possibly obscure) the situation with more words, let me show you a drawing of what's really going on (at least, in my brain). You'll have to excuse my shabby artistic skills, but hopefully the deformation retract is a little clearer now:

[image]

but this one seems even more confusing. It's like there is no circle at all inside this solid sphere in this sketch?

Comment: Imagine the white circle as a tiny tunnel around the core of an apple. Then imagine widening the tunnel until the core has become 1 dimensional and the tunnel pushes up against the boundary of the apple.

Comment: I got the picture, but why can I imagine the circle to be essentially a cylinder?

Comment: First imagine the circle as a tubular tunnel. You can enlarge it in the vertical direction more than in the horizontal to get it to look more like a cylinder if you want.

Comment: Note, though, that even though the sphere-with-diameter can retract onto the wedge $S^2\vee S^1$ (so they are homotopy equivalent), it doesn't deformation retract because the latter is not a subspace of the former. So showing $\Bbb R^3\setminus S^1$ deformation retracts to the sphere-with-diameter is enough to show it retracts onto $S^2\vee S^1$, but it is not enough to show it *deformation* retracts.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the first sketch is probably not worth spending a lot of time deciphering.

In the first drawing of the second sketch, you have to imagine the white space around the "bulb" in the middle really goes all the way around the bulb, and that the bulb connects to the "outer shell" that is the sphere at its narrow top and bottom. That white space is the missing circle.

Comment: Is the white space inside the sphere or is it "lying" on the boundary of the sphere?

Comment: @EmilGrönberg: It's "inside" the sphere. Another way to think about it is start with the thickened shell of the sphere. This is topologically just a sphere now. Add a vertical diameter inside the sphere connecting the poles. This is no longer topologically just a sphere. Thicken the pipe in a "bulb-like" manner until we reach the first picture in the second sketch. If you can still picture it, it should be clear that we didn't change the topology from when we just had a pipe, and there is now clearly a torus missing from inside the solid ball. That torus retracts onto a circle. Hence "inside".

Comment: So I would kinda put a cylinder inside the sphere?

Comment: @EmilGrönberg: A solid cylinder, yes. That's what I meant by the vertical diameter being thickened to a pipe. The image in your mind should be essentially the drawing in the third picture.